# SharePoint 2013 layout questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am working on SharePoint 2013 server, and I have the following questions about the following layout issues:-

1. When I try to edit the text layout for my community site from (PageeditText Layout) I could not find an option to have three columns with footer? There are a three column layout without header and footer OR two columns with footer. While there is no layout for three columns with footer, so is there a way to add this text layout?
2. I have a prompted links, which when clicked will open a pop-up window. so my question if I want to replace the prompted links with a normal html link, how I can force the SharePoint to open the target URL for the html link , in a new pop-up window, same as prompted links behavior?
3. I want to remove the SharePoint logo on the upper left side, and to shift the Quick lunch left side links to the upper most. Currently I have provide a white image as the logo to hide SharePoint logo, but the left side links will be shown under the image, while I need to shift the link in the left to the upper most side of the page as show below:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

1. There isn't layout with three columns and footer. You have to create it with SharePoint Designer or in visual studio
2. There is no out of the box way to do this. But you can put follow this link [current navigation link in Modal Pop up](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/03360fbf-545d-40cf-87c8-2cd5eb146413/current-navigation-link-in-modal-pop-up)
3. You have several ways to achieve this. You could modify master page with designer and test to modify this snippet `<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass=”ms-siteicon-img” name=”onetidHeadbnnr0″ id=”onetidHeadbnnr2″ LogoImageUrl=”/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=23″ runat=”server”>` by this one `<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass=”ms-siteicon-img” name=”onetidHeadbnnr0″ id=”onetidHeadbnnr2″ LogoImageUrl=”″ runat=”server”>` You could also modify `ms-siteicon-img` class with `display:none`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but which master page i should modify the t4.master or another one ?

Comment: The seattle.master